# How to skip to a certain row by name instead of number with python read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to skip to a certain row in an excel sheet but by the name located at the rows first box, what I mean is:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| num | num | num |
| num | num | num |
| num | num | num |
| here | num | num |

I want to skip and start reading at the 'here' index but not by skipping to the number it is on but by some other way such as trying to go to the name that is in the box 'here'. Is there a way to do this besides by first iterating through the rows till I want while keeping an index counter?

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", header = 26)
```

Will skip the first 25 rows (0-indexed).

Comment: Could you update your post with a sample of your file (in csv format and/or a screenshot), please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to get the index number of the row with the value `here`. `df[df['A']=='here'].index[0]` will filter the dataframe for all rows with `here` in column `A` and will return the index of the first item.

You can use this index number to slice the dataframe:

```
df = df[df[df['A']=='here'].index[0]:] # add .reset_index(drop=True) to reset the index
```

Result:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | here | num | num |